# Distance to forest edge in R

Tags: raster, r, rgeos, st-distance, edge-detection

I have a raster layer consisting 41 forest polygons and would like to calculate the distance of forest pixels to the edge within each forest polygon. I tried the code below
but the result looks like the opposite of what i want.

How do I do the correct calculation in R?

````r
forestNA <- raster("glc_crop_aoi")
forestNA[forestNA] <- 1
forestNA[forestNA == 1] <- NA
#create a distance to edge raster for forest land cover
forest.dist <- raster::distance(forestNA)
writeRaster(forest.dist, "forest.dist.tif")
forest.dist <- raster("forest.dist.tif")
forest.dist_respld <- resample(forest.dist, ndvi_1816_june_aoi)
writeRaster(forest.dist_respld, "forest.dist_respld", 
            format = "GTiff", overwrite = TRUE)
plot(forest.dist_respld)
hist(forest.dist_respld)```
````

#my raster looks like this below

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10608, 6436, 68273088  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 9.863767, 10.16501  (x, y)
extent     : 645189.8, 708673, 5448158, 5555988  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : r_tmp_2021-09-13_235057_2052_13476.grd 
names      : layer 
values     : 62, 162  (min, max)
```

my result plot looks like this below

[image]

my histogram looks like this below

[image]

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, changing the `==` in line 3 to `=!` should do the trick.